# Godot: how to pause

Tags: godot

I am trying to pause my game whenever you hit the space key, but it never seems to work.

```
func _input(event):
    if event.is_action_pressed("space"):
        get_tree().paused = true
    
    if event.is_action_pressed("space") and get_tree().paused:
        get_tree().paused = false
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 3):

Back in the old days there was something we programmers did called a desk check. An early motivation to do that was that running code was expensive, later it was that debugging was hard. Right now, we have plenty of debugging tools, but I cannot step through the code with you… So, let us do a desk check.

---

So, some input event happens, and the code starts to execute. We get to the first line:

```
if event.is_action_pressed("space")
```

Let us say that `event.is_action_pressed("space")` is `true` (write that down, we need it later), since that is what we are interested in checking. So the execution flow enters the `if` statement. Which takes us to this line:

```
get_tree().paused = true
```

Now `get_tree().paused` is `true` (write that down, we need it later). We get to the next line:

```
if event.is_action_pressed("space") and get_tree().paused:
```

We have already established that `event.is_action_pressed("space")` is `true` and also that `get_tree().paused` is `true` (those are the things we wrote down). So the execution flow enters the `if` statement. Which takes us to the following line:

```
get_tree().paused = false
```

And thus, `get_tree().paused` will now be `false`.

We conclude that executing the code will result in `get_tree().paused` being `false`, which supports the reported behavior of "never seems to work".

---

Now that you have an understanding of why it does not work, I would like to encourage you to come up with a solution.

*Sadly that does not make for a complete answer… Even if it helps more in the long run…*

Let us begin by not checking `event.is_action_pressed("space")` twice:

```
func _input(event):
    if event.is_action_pressed("space"):
        get_tree().paused = true   
        if get_tree().paused:
            get_tree().paused = false
```

Yes, that does not look good. We want to toggle `get_tree().paused`, so let us do that:

```
func _input(event):
    if event.is_action_pressed("space"):
        if get_tree().paused:
            get_tree().paused = false
        else:
            get_tree().paused = true
```

We, of course, can write that in less lines of code. For example, we can set `get_tree().paused` to its own negation:

```
func _input(event):
    if event.is_action_pressed("space"):
        get_tree().paused = not get_tree().paused
```

We could even collapse that into a single line. But shorter code is not the goal. And I believe written this way is easy to read and to extend.